# placeholder issue with jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I noticed today that we have an issue with jquery Validate when used in conjunction with placeholder text.

Example:

```
<div class="sort left">
<label for="username" class="inlineelement">Username</label>
<input id="registername"  type="text" placeholder="your name" autocomplete="off" class="required"></input>
```

I noticed that , if we validate our form using jquery Validate ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods )

Is there a work around for this, or should be go back to focus html ( placeholder text ) within our form fields ?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.5.1 with jQuery Validate 1.8.0 on Chrome 11.0... and the plugin validates correctly. The place holder text appears in the input and if I don't enter any text, the error message appears. Which version of jQuery and the plugin are you using?

Comment: We are using 1.5.2 jquery and jQuery validation plug-in pre-1.5.2 ( couldnt find a later version of validation )

Comment: Latest version of jQuery Validate: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ - works with jQuery 1.5.2.

Comment: Ok now have it, but similar issue. I think we may have overlooked something painfully obvious , our required class is same for all firlds. class="required" and our script is: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate({
  rules: {
    reason: "required"
  }
  });
  });
Not sure what else it could be

Comment: Please edit your question to fully describe the issue you're having.

Answer (score 15):

I was coming across the same issue. After some messing around, found a workaround with this custom method. This custom method will accommodate placeholders.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("placeholder", function(value, element) {
  return value!=$(element).attr("placeholder");
}, jQuery.validator.messages.required);
```

Tag this line at the end of the `additional-methods.js` file.

You'll then use it as follows:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    username: {required: true, placeholder: true},
  },
  message: {
    username: {
      required: "Username required", placeholder: "Username required",
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: One issue I can see with this is if the person wants to enter a value the same as the placeholder.

Comment: Note this has a problem in that it causes all elements with placeholders to behave as required even if they aren't marked as required.

Comment: similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904017/jquery-validate-how-to-ignore-placeholder-text-produce-error-on-default-blank

Answer (score 5):

This is generic way of validating placeholders (use following code AFTER validation logic initialization).
It works by injecting custom logic into all validation methods.

```
$(function () {
    $.each($.validator.methods, function (key, value) {
        $.validator.methods[key] = function () {
            var el = $(arguments[1]);
            if (el.is('[placeholder]') && arguments[0] == el.attr('placeholder'))
                arguments[0] = '';

            return value.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could script around it perhaps.

This will remove `placeholder` attribute on submit, and restore them in the event of an error.

```
var placeholders = {};
$('form').validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {

       $(form).find(':input[placeholder]').each(function() {
          var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder'); 
          placeholders[placeholder] = this;
          $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
       });       

       form.submit();
   },

   invalidHandler: function() {

      $.each(placeholders, function(placeholder, element) {
          $(element).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
      });

   }

});
```

Comment: the $.each function is missing its close parenthesis. But, beyond that, IE spits back that placeholders is undefined on the same line.

Comment: @Micah Fixed missing `)`. Have you defined `placeholders` ?

Comment: oops, forgot to define `placeholders`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with a form i am working on. You can use [the jq-watermark plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/jq-watermark/) to do your placeholders/watermarks.

It works with jQuery Validate plug-in, i.e. doesn't obstruct validation.

Answer (score 2):

My quick solution:

```
            $(".validateForm").submit(function(){
            $(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("placeholder") == $(this).val())$(this).val("");
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you add custom rules ie: email:true, then the validation is not ignored. 
So if you look in additional-methods.js which comes bundled with the jquery validation download, there is a rule called alphanumeric. This has all of the default required functionality. Just use this custom rule and it should work. I am using http://widgetulous.com/placeholderjs/ for placeholder support on older browsers. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").validate();
    $(function () {
                $.each($.validator.methods, function (key, value) {
                $.validator.methods[key] = function () {
                var el = $(arguments[1]);
                if (el.is('[placeholder]') && arguments[0] == el.attr('placeholder'))
                    arguments[0] = '';
                    return value.apply(this, arguments);
                    };
                 });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest version of jquery.validate from http://jqueryvalidation.org/

version 1.11.1 seems to have solved this issue for me =D

Comment: Confirmed - Latest v1.11.1 used in conjunction with [jquery.placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) plugin fixes issues.

Answer (score 0):

I used a trick, if you focus on the field, the placeholder appears.. The following code will focus and blur all of the input fields.

```
function tabFields(){
    $('#form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        $(this).focus().blur();
    });
}
```