# jquery.validate + html5 placeholder | help binding

Tags: jquery, html, validation

If anyone has tried to use the jQuery.Validate plugin in conjunction with the HTML5 placeholder you probabbly know that the placeholder text allows for a submission of the input, when it shouldn't.

I found this bit of code, that might help fix that problem but am unsure how to bind it to the event.
I've tried the documentation, for the plugin but am not having any luck with the syntax. Probabbly a quick fix.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z566u/6/

***If you include a "for" attribute on the label, you need to also include a "name" attribute on the input. 
**That was the problem**

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues with native placeholders and the [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). There's an issue with your demo though: you haven't actually loaded the plugin. Here's a demo with the plugin loaded, no configuration, and seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Z566u/1/ Can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: hmmm, it's only validating the first input, but all the inputs are required. Is it possible the html5 is throwing it off?  ***link updated

Comment: Similar question and some worth-looking-at answers [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066540/placeholder-issue-with-jquery-validate](here).

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z566u/9/) with no placeholders, no configuration, no CSS, and it seems to be the same as all the other demos - validates one by one instead of all at once... which makes me think it's not specifically related to `placeholder`. Side note: you were missing the equal sign for all your `for` attributes, adding them did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @madmartigan Thanks for that, I caught that syntax error too. I just did this exact same test, it seems so strange that it is only validating the first input.

Comment: I also noticed that if you focus the input box it begins the validation for that input.

Comment: I found out the problem:

If you include a "for" attribute on the label, you need to also include a "name" attribute on the input.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe we didn't catch that sooner. The problem has nothing to do with `for` and *everything* to do with requiring a `name` on your inputs. Calling `validate()` with no arguments simply makes all fields "required", but of course in real life you need to process the data, so `name`s are essential. Feel free to post your solution as an answer, in the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

*If you include a "for" attribute on the label, you need to also include a "name" attribute on the input. **That was the problem

Comment: Validate I believe requires all inputs to have names; the 'for' attribute on a label points to the ID, not the name.