# Placeholders in IE that work with jquery validator

Tags: jquery, forms, html, validation

I'm trying to validate my html 5 form that uses placeholders in IE7 + 8.

I used the valid() call from the Validation plugin for jquery. That means I cant use this solution: [placeholder issue with jQuery Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066540/placeholder-issue-with-jquery-validate). My problem is the same though. The placeholder script I use adds the placeholder text to the value attribute. When the validation is called the script reads the placeholder text as valid input.

I don't do full validation because the form is spread over several 'tabs' so needs to be validated before the next section is shown. This is non negotionalble

My placeholder script:

```
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur();

    $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        })
    });
```

and here is where I call the validation:

```
if (elements.valid() === 0) {
    valid = 0;
}

if (valid) {
    $('.form').removeClass('error');
    $(this).closest('section').hide().next().show();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try [generic way of validating placeholders][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15898568/657357

Answer (score 2):

You can try to redefine the default required function of validator. Before calling the validation add this:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("required", function(value, element, param) {
        // check if dependency is met
        if ( !this.depend(param, element) ) {
            return "dependency-mismatch";
        }
        if ( element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "select" ) {
            // could be an array for select-multiple or a string, both are fine this way
            var val = $(element).val();
            return val && val.length > 0;
        }
        if ( this.checkable(element) ) {
            return this.getLength(value, element) > 0;
        }
        default:
            var placeholderval = $(element).attr('placeholder');
          //if some placeholder values are actually default values, just use "default" attribute to mark them
            var defaultvar = ($(element).attr('default') === undefined);
            return ($.trim(value).length > 0 && ($.trim(value)!=$.trim(placeholderval) || !defaultvar));
    }, jQuery.validator.messages.required);
```